# How to MODIFY rather than REPLACE the Vivaldi User-agent header?

Tags: linux, automation, privacy, user-agent, vivaldi

I already know how to replace the `User-agent` HTTP request header in Vivaldi.

But if I do that, I have to provide a full, complete `User-agent` string. After a short time, this will get outdated and start looking suspicious/fake. Version numbers change, etc. Having to manually keep this up to date is a nightmare. There isn't even any reliable way to get the current full `User-agent` for Chrome on Windows when you don't have it installed yourself and can manually visit a webpage in it.

Instead, I would like to **replace** part of whatever is the current `User-agent` string. I want to simply replace "Windows" with "Linux" in whatever is the current `User-agent` in Vivaldi.

Is it possible? If not, I'm forced to announce to every webpage that I'm using Linux, which I don't want to do. I want to blend in, using whatever is the current most common `User-agent` string.

Years ago, I spent a lot of time trying to find a webpage which provides this data, but none does. At least not reliably/updated and not blocking robots. There is no use of a webpage which provides information if you can't connect to it and fetch the latest data from it.

If there were such a webpage, I could automate checking for it and then auto-editing all my Vivaldi shortcuts to use my own User-agent as an argument. Not a very clean or nice solution, but even this isn't possible due to the lack of any such reliable webpage.

Answer (score 3):

You need an extension for this.

One of the first on Google is
[Requestly](https://requestly.io/),
which is free for basic usage.

The Requestly documentation article on
[Modify User Agent](https://docs.requestly.io/desktop-app/mac/http-modifications/user-agent-rule)
can get you started.

I have never used this tool, and you may find a list of alternatives
[here](https://alternativeto.net/software/requestly/).

Comment: Are you really sure that those support this? I already have an extension which is called ModHeader, but it doesn't seem to allow this "advanced" usage. I don't trust things anyway...